# Unknown chipset error when installing

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Elementary OS Freya but I keep running into an error. I use a USB for the installation.

When the system boots I get an error stating

```
Unknown chipset: 0x124000a1
Failed to create 0x80000080, -22
```

I tried the suggestions found in [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/problem-with-nouveau-cant-install) question but it did not help.

My system specs are:

- Intel Core i5-4690K
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 980
- Samsung Evo 850 1TB
- Gigabyte Z97-D3H-CF

I also tried the latest version of Ubuntu and the problem does not exist there.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has probably already been answered in [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/problem-with-nouveau-cant-install).
(Could anyone more knowledgable regarding kernel modules and drivers please confirm these two problems are the same?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the post you linked is the exact one I already mentioned in my original question. As I stated there the solution did not work and I still got the same error.

Comment: Oops, my bad. It was indeed the same post.